# Fallback storage account (or multiple storage accounts) for Azure CDN

Tags: azure, azure-cdn

I can configure the Azure CDN against a single storage account presently. What I'm wondering is in the event of a disaster, where that particular region becomes unavailable (outages etc..). If I need to refresh the cache at that point I don't have any regional fallbacks. What is the correct way of supporting multiple storage accounts with the CDN?

One way that I can see it is the Traffic Manager. Traffic Manager receives the request and sends it to one of the X CDNs configured for X Storage Accounts based on performance. That way if one of the regions become unavailable, Traffic Manager should fallback to another one. This is an expensive solution though, so I'm looking for something where I can get one CDN and X Storage Accounts ideally and the CDN should handle the world-wide performance, along with a fallback region.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the steps to configure AFD:

1. Create AFD from Portal.
2. Click on Front Door Designer. You will have 3 sections. First is Frontend which will be already configured. Then Baclkend Pools and Routing rules.
3. Click on Backend Pools and add a new backend pool. Select Storage as Host type and then pick your Primary Storage blob page and provide priority as 1.
4. Once that is done configure the Health probes. Then add your second Storage blob page and then provide priority as 2.
5. Configure Routing rules and make sure you have /* as matching pattern. Also you can enable caching in the rule and you can cache based on the query string. Moreover if have a dynamic page, then you can enable dynamic compression.

Once that is done, try accessing AFD URL and check how it works.

Here is the Public Documentation for your reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-routing-methods

Comment: Looked into this thanks. It looks like it's closer to what I've been looking for, but not exactly like the CDN. You can still specify the caching per routing rule though, so presumably it acts like a CDN. Please update your answer to reflect so and I'll accept it as answer.

Comment: Edited it. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: @msrini-MSIT so in this setup Azure CDN is not required? In step 2 you said FE will already be configured - you mean with the *.azurefd.net domain or would it pick up the CDN endpoint as the FE (input) to the designer logic?

Comment: You don't need CDN. Azure Frontdoor is the combination of CDN and L7 capabilities. So, FE will have azurefd.net domain and you can add custom domain if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You try using Azure FrontDoor. It is a combination of CDN and L7 load balancer. You can try implementing your ask with Azure FrontDoor.

Let me know if you face any difficulties.

Comment: Can you please provide more details to this? Perhaps a few screenshots? How can I configure FrontDoor to achieve what I'm looking?